# Open a WebView URL from Plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, plist

Is there a way to retreive a url that I have inside a Plist and making a webview from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can open the plist using something like:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"your.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path] retain];
```

Then you will be able to find your URL in the `plistDictionary`.

Comment: Actually, the url is not the only thing parameter in the Plist, it doesn't matter? Od will I have to specify something else?

Comment: @CarlosNegron: you should be able to just do `[plistDictionary objectForKey:@"key_of_the_url"]`.

Comment: No luck :/ here's my code:
`code`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
 NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
 
 [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"twitter"];
 
 NSLog(@"%@", plistDictionary);

Comment: @CarlosNegron: no, you need `NSLog(@"%@", [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"twitter"]);`

Comment: it showed up as (null). Weird, it is loaded with some text, since I can see it in the tableview, but I just want to click it and open the website :/

Comment: You will likely need to catch a tap on the URL, and call something like : `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]];`

Comment: If I type the users URL it works, but I have over 20 users, I need to read the URL from the Plist :/ It's going to be updated constantly.

Comment: @CarlosNegron: yes I understand, just replace with your URL. Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to understand how NSDictionary works.

Comment: I just found out that the Plist is (Root: Array, items: Dictionary, Parameters: String). Does that changes anything?